# Unable to capture value of element using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to extract the content of dumpName using jq, but it does not work. I have attempted to simplify the structure of the original file as I cannot post the full details here.

I would also like to get the content of param2. This can be collected in a separate jq statement if needed.

```
{
  "get": {
    "download": {
      "ebR": true,
      "detail": [
        {
          "downloadHost": "xxx.jgs.com",
          "downloadURL": "xxx.jgs.com",
          "dumpInfo": {
            "dumpCategory": "Other",
            "dumpContentType": "UNKNOWN",
            "dumpId": test,
            "dumpName": "name_of_dump",
            "dumpSize": 1200,
            "dumpStatus": "COMPLETED",
            "dumpUploadDate": "date",
            "vis": "who_see_it"
          },
          "datastore": [
            {
              "param1": "random_val",
              "param2": "random_val"
            },
            {
              "param1": "testtest",
              "param2": "testtest"
            }
          ],
          "Info": {
            "webpage": "test@test.com"
          }
        }
  }
}
}
```

Desired output:

```
name_of_dump
random_val
testtest
```

Previous attempts:

```
jq '.[] | .[]'   # gives section from { ebR
jq '.[] | .[] | .[]'   # gives error:
```

true
jq: error (at :399): Cannot iterate over string ("http://www...)

```
jq '.[] | .[] | .[] | .dumpName'  # gives error:
```

jq: error (at :399): Cannot index boolean with string "dumpName"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recurse down the JSON with the proper object/array names. Using plain `.[]` notation won't let you achieve this

```
jq --raw-output '.get.download.detail[] | .dumpInfo.dumpName, .datastore[0].param1, .datastore[1].param1'
```

Also the input JSON isn't syntactically valid. See this [jqplay URL](https://jqplay.org/s/q4PbotUcky) which shows the filter working in run-time.

Answer (score 2):

also, an *alternative* easy way to display content of JSON is to use walk-path based unix utility **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**

```
bash $ <download.json jtc -qq -w'<dumpName>l' -w'<param2>l:'
name_of_dump
random_val
testtest
bash $
```

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` - shell cli tool for JSON operations

Answer (score 1):

You might like to consider this one-liner:

```
jq '.. | (.dumpName? // empty), (.param2? // empty)' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the user asked to display **dumpName** and **param2**, here is the correct code:

```
jq -r '.get.download.detail[] | .dumpInfo.dumpName, .datastore[].param2'
```

Output:

```
name_of_dump
random_val
testtest
```

As the user (Inian) mentioned above, your JSON file is not valid.

Here is the valid JSON:

```
{
  "get": {
    "download": {
      "ebR": true,
      "detail": [
        {
          "downloadHost": "xxx.jgs.com",
          "downloadURL": "xxx.jgs.com",
          "dumpInfo": {
            "dumpCategory": "Other",
            "dumpContentType": "UNKNOWN",
            "dumpId": "test",
            "dumpName": "name_of_dump",
            "dumpSize": 1200,
            "dumpStatus": "COMPLETED",
            "dumpUploadDate": "date",
            "vis": "who_see_it"
          },
          "datastore": [
            {
              "param1": "random_val",
              "param2": "random_val"
            },
            {
              "param1": "testtest",
              "param2": "testtest"
            }
          ],
          "Info": {
            "webpage": "test@test.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```